# Correct way to sleep in PythonOperator airflow

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

I need to perform a sleep within a function of a `PythonOperator`.  I noticed time.sleep causes the backend db to lock.  I cannot use a wait task or anything, I must perform a sleep inside the middle of a python function.  Using `time.sleep(15*60)` causes the db to lock up.  What other sleep options do I have?  Also, why does `time.sleep()` cause the DB to lock?

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by DB lockup? what exactly is effected?